# How to check NULL pointer and run function with && in C

Tags: c, function

Here is my test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char  u8,  * pu8;
typedef unsigned short u16, * pu16;
typedef unsigned       u32, * pu32;

void sum(int a, int b) {
    printf("%d\n", a + b);
}
/*
void temp_fun1(void (*fn) (int, int)) {
    fn && fn(1, 2);
}*/

void temp_fun2(int * num) {
    num && (*num)++;
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 6;
    
    temp_fun2(&a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    temp_fun2(NULL);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    
    // temp_fun1(sum);
    // temp_fun1(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

As was expected, function temp_fun2 does well.
But, temp_fun1 raised error

```
./main.c:12:8: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('void (*)(int, int)' and 'void')
    fn && fn(1, 2);
    ~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

How do I do the way to solve this problem? I want to check NULL with &&.

I do

```
fn && (*fn)(1, 2);
```

but result is same.

Comment: You can do `fn && (fn(1,2), 42)`. You shouldn't, but you can.

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking but you can replace `fn && fn(1, 2)` with something like `fn ? (*fn)(1, 2) : NULL;`. The error is telling you that you can't use the `&&` binary operator between the two types.

Answer (score 4):

The return type of `fn` is `void` so it can't be used as part of an expression.

You should use `if` instead, which also makes what you're doing more clear.

```
if (fn) fn(1, 2);
```

Comment: And to be clear, this is something you should be doing by default; there's no benefit to `&&` in most cases unless you're actually using it for a boolean test (and if you were, it would be obvious why a `void` returning function doesn't make sense). `num && (*num)++;` should have been `if (num) (*num)++;` in the same way. If you think the latter is bad because `if` should use braces and be spread across multiple lines, then you should know that `num && (*num)++;` is not an improvement; it's got the same problems as one-line `if`s, and it's more confusing (by virtue of hiding control flow).